# Stacking dataframes sideways with common column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes like-

```
a b c     c d f
2 4 6     6 7 1
4 7 9     9 5 8
```

Now I want to make a new dataframe which looks like-

```
a b c d f   
2 4 6 7 1
4 7 9 5 8
```

I tried merge,concat,append but no of them worked for me when using on the real dataset.
like-

```
pd.append([df,df2],axis=1)
pd.concat([df,df2], ignore_index=True,axis=1)
```

Comment: `df1.combine_first(df2)
`

Comment: @Wen what about thr common column?

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2], 1)` would definitely work.

Comment: @ubuntu_noob can you clarify what you mean by they didn't work? Are you getting an error? Is the resulting dataframe different that what you expected?

Comment: @johnchase it is different than expected

Comment: @johnchase it is showing ValueError: Shape of passed values is (30, 100806), indices imply (30, 634)

Comment: Cool, thank you for the clarification. The question isn't entirely clear as written. I would suggest coming up with a reproducible example, I think it will help people give better answers. For example the data set in your question is not the dataset giving the error so it's hard to know what the actual issue you are running into is. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a guide on what I am talking about

Comment: `df2[['c','d','f']] = df1[['c','d','f']]`

Comment: @RafaelC but this wont work when there are a lot of column names

Comment: @ubuntu_noob try to be more specific. Just saying "this won't work" is not helpful. Answer *why* that won't work.

Comment: That error indicates that the actual dataframes you're using are very different from the example, to the point that this is not a usefully phrased question. For instance my answer which someone (you)? downvoted does give the correct answer for the sample you have posted.

Comment: Deleted my answer which was correct given your example, since you downvoted it because you couldn't be bothered to provide an example that corresponds to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2,4],
               'b': [4,7],
               'c': [6,9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c': [6,9],
               'e': [7,5],
               'f': [1,8]})

df = df1.merge(df2, left_on='c', right_on='c', how='inner')
print(df)
```

Comment: This is the same as my solution below.

Comment: @A.Leistra Agreed. Thanks!